# A deck of cards is split into $2$ halves of $26$ cards each. What is the probability of one partition containing all $4$ aces?

Tags: probability

A deck of cards is split into $2$ halves of $26$ cards each.  What is the probability of one partition containing all $4$ aces?

Find the probability corresponding to this. It deals with the concepts of partitions which explicitly added twist.

Comment: Please, instead of uploading images, type your question and add what have you tried so far, in order to encourage us to help you.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your question rather than posting a link since links may be deleted.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, when you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have tried and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Number the parts: $1,2$.

The probability that part $1$ has all $4$ aces is:

> $$\frac{\binom{26}4\binom{26}0}{\binom{52}4}$$

It cannot happen that both parts have all $4$ aces.

Comment: How did you get that "Click to show Spoiler"?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan A spoiler is achieved by starting the line with ">!" and becomes visible if the cursor is on it.

Comment: we wont do ${\binom{52}{26}}$ ?How do we split it into 2 parts?

Comment: @Damn1o1 You can indeed also find it as $\frac{\binom44\binom{48}{22}}{\binom{52}{26}}$. That gives the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

We can divide the four aces over the two partitions, ignoring the other cards. For the first ace it is irrelevant in which partition it is placed, but the other aces must be in the same partition as the first. So the probability that all aces are in the same partition is given by $$1\cdot \frac{25}{51}\cdot\frac{24}{50}\cdot\frac{23}{49}=\frac{92}{833}\approx 0.11.$$